# Typescript testing - run code before importing a class instance

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

I am writing unit tests for a class instance I am exporting from my TS like so:

**index.ts**

```
export { myClass as MyClass } from './my-class';
```

**my-class.ts**

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    const session = window.localstorage.getItem('some_session');
    this.restoreSession(session);
  }
  restoreSession(session) {
    this.activeSession = session;
  }
  getUserName() {
    return this.activeSession.user.name;
  }
}
export const myClass = new MyClass();
```

With my test, I am trying to figure out whether I can provide a value of my choosing for the localstorage item prior to MyClass being imported in the test.

I tried the following below, thinking use of `before` may help me:

**my-class.spec.ts**

```
import { MyClass } from '../src/index.ts';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { describe, before } from 'mocha';

const persistedSession = { user: { name: 'bob' } };

before(() => {  
  window.localStorage.setItem('some_session', JSON.stringify(persistedSession));
});
describe('After loading a persisted session, and retrieving the users name', () => {
  it('should return the value of the users name', () => {
    expect(MyClass.getUserName()).to.equal('bob');
  });
});
```

This doesnt pass as getUserName() returns an empty string at the point the test runs, and I suspect this is because the class instance is getting imported\constructed before my test specs given I am exporting a class instance anyway.

I can only think of refactoring my TS, to export the class, but not an instance, and then I would just new it up as needed.

But I wanted to know if there was still a way I could set my localstorage items before my class gets imported in

Comment: @ABOS - ah sorry that was a typo in the code snippet, I have fixed now

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, class instance is instantiated before storage mock is populated, so perhaps you can try with the following,

```
class MyClass {
  private _activeSession;

  constructor() { }

  get activeSession() {
    return this._activeSession || this._activeSession=window.localstorage.getItem('some_session');
  }

  clearActiveSession() {
    this._activeSession = undefined;
  } 

  getUserName() {
    // guard against undefined etc ...
    return this.activeSession.user.name;
  }
}  

export const myClass = new MyClass();
```

The idea is to `lazy load` session storage stuff so you can mock them on demand. The code is not tested though, hope it works/helps.